# Plot Multiple Charts in one in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, android-canvas, mpandroidchart

I have to plot two different dataSets in a single graph.

**DataSet-1**

```
    String[] xAxisOne = new String[] {
            "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
    };

    float[] dataInput = {
            1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f
    };
```

**DataSet-2**

```
    String[] xAxisTwo = new String[] {
            "0", "2", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9"
    };

    float[] dataIn = {
            3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f, 8f, 9f
    };
```

In the above data, DataSet-1 is reference by which graph is created.
DataSet-2 has to be plotted in the same with different set of X-Values **{xAxisTwo}**.

In existing Implementation, first 6 values **{dataInput}** are plotted & next 6 values **{dataIn}** are plotted with reference to `xAxisOne`, How to plot as required.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with LineChart and unifying the xAxis and ignoring the "null" point for each dataset. See the code below:

```
//float[] dataInput = {
//      1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f
//};

//values for datainput Dataset1 at your axisone positions
ArrayList<Entry> dataset1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
dataset1.add(new Entry(1f, 0));
dataset1.add(new Entry(2f, 1));
dataset1.add(new Entry(3f, 2));
dataset1.add(new Entry(4f, 3));
dataset1.add(new Entry(5f, 4));
dataset1.add(new Entry(6f, 5));
dataset1.add(new Entry(7f, 6));

//float[] dataIn = {
//      3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f, 8f, 9f
//};

//values for datainput Dataset2 at your axisone positions
ArrayList<Entry> dataset2 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
dataset2.add(new Entry(3f, 0));
dataset2.add(new Entry(4f, 2));
dataset2.add(new Entry(5f, 4));
dataset2.add(new Entry(6f, 5));
dataset2.add(new Entry(7f, 6));
dataset2.add(new Entry(8f, 7));
dataset2.add(new Entry(9f, 8));

//String[] xAxisOne = new String[] {
//      "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
//};

///String[] xAxisTwo = new String[] {
///     "0", "2", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9"
///};


// Union from xAxisOne and xAxisTwo
String[] xAxis = new String[] {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9"};


ArrayList<LineDataSet> lines = new ArrayList<LineDataSet> ();

LineDataSet lDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(dataset1, "DataSet1");
lDataSet1.setColor(Color.RED);
lDataSet1.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
lines.add(lDataSet1);
lines.add(new LineDataSet(dataset2, "DataSet2"));

LineChart chart = (LineChart) getView().findViewById(R.id.chart);
chart.setData(new LineData(xAxis, lines));
```

The final result will be:

[image: Final chart]

Looks that the red line of dataset1 have 2 more points than blue line.
If the dataset1 have only these two points(at position 1 and 3) like this:

```
ArrayList<Entry> dataset1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    dataset1.add(new Entry(2f, 1));
    dataset1.add(new Entry(4f, 3));
```

it will be the result:

[image]

Comment: getting issue `varargs mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to ILineDataSet`

Answer (score 2):

Well this will need an update as of version 3:

For multiple lines , you will need multiple datasets. Assuming you have created two data sets.

```
LineDataSet dataSetReported = new LineDataSet(entriesReported, "Reported");
LineDataSet dataSetCalculated = new LineDataSet(entriesCalculated, "Calculated");
```

You will need a list of ILINEDATASET to accommodate both datasets created. Simply create a list and add datasets.

```
List<ILineDataSet> lines = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
lines.add(dataSetReported);
lines.add(dataSetCalculated);
```

Display it on chart as:

```
LineData data = new LineData(lines);
chart.setData(data);
chart.invalidate();
```

Refer [here](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/) for documentation from original author.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this Line Chart passing multiple Data Set

```
LineChart lineChart1 = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new Entry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new Entry(10f, 3));
    entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new Entry(9f, 5));

    ArrayList<Entry> entry = new ArrayList<>();
    entry.add(new Entry(3f, 0));
    entry.add(new Entry(10f, 1));
    entry.add(new Entry(4f, 2));
    entry.add(new Entry(14f, 3));
    entry.add(new Entry(12f, 4));
    entry.add(new Entry(5f, 5));
    ArrayList<LineDataSet> lines = new ArrayList<LineDataSet> ();
    String[] xAxis = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6"};
    LineDataSet lDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(entries, "DataSet1");
    lDataSet1.setDrawFilled(true);
    lines.add(lDataSet1);

    LineDataSet lDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(entry, "DataSet2");
    lDataSet2.setDrawFilled(true);
    lines.add(lDataSet2);

    lineChart1.setData(new LineData(xAxis, lines));
    lineChart1.animateY(5000);
}
```

Comment: Can do it on one line with different filled color?

Comment: @hpAndro set1.setColor(Color.RED);