# MPAndroidChart XY plot - independent X values?

Tags: android, scatter-plot, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart library to plot some data from a few sensors.  I've found similar questions on SO, but no solutions:
[Plot Multiple Charts in one in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873445/plot-multiple-charts-in-one-in-mpandroidchart)
[MPAndroidChart How to represent multiple dataset object with different number of points in the same chart line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116357/mpandroidchart-how-to-represent-multiple-dataset-object-with-different-number-of/28549480#28549480)

The sensors create data at different rates, and each data sample is stored as data structure like this:  .

I would like to be able to plot both sensor values on the same chart as two independent traces.  However, after attempting to do this using a LineChart (which claims to be able to plot multiple traces on the same graph) I discovered that the MPAndroidChart Library requires that all data be stored as , with the "xIndex" being an index into a single universal (to the traces on the chart) array of X values.

However, this makes plotting data from non-synchronous sources very difficult.

Is there a way, with MPAndroidChart, to create multiple XY traces with *independent* axis on *both* the X and Y axis?  That is, can I plot something like this:

trace1 = Array of ()
trace2 = another array of ()
trace3...

The only suggestion I saw for a solution was the answer (given by the MPAndroidChart developer) to this question:  [MPAndroidChart How to represent multiple dataset object with different number of points in the same chart line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116357/mpandroidchart-how-to-represent-multiple-dataset-object-with-different-number-of/28549480#28549480).  However, I'm concerned that using a tag to identify X values will result in slow graphing performance as the dataset grows larger, because I suspect that the library will have to do a lot of string compares and searches to find which Xaxis value corresponds to each Y value.

If it can't be done with MPAndroidChart, can anyone suggest a good library that can do it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *bump*  seriously, nothing?

Comment: I have answered this question at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873445/plot-multiple-charts-in-one-in-mpandroidchart/31868729#31868729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, in case anyone else runs into this and needs a suggestion...I've found that Android Plot (http://androidplot.com/) meets my needs.  It has good native support for XY graphs and seems like a good package all around.

I wish the javaDocs were a little more developed - a lot of functions have no descriptions, just the function declaration.  That's not always enough to go off of.  But so far it's working well.